# Selecting cells next to a scattered range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having difficulty selecting a range of cells in VBA. I already have a range of cells that are scattered, but am trying to add the three cells to the right of each cell in the range to the selection.

So far I've tried:
`SelectedRange("Hi").Resize(1, 4).Select`, which gives an error when ran; I assume it does not work because SelectedRange is a range and not a cell.

SelectedRange() searches for the input string and returns a range of each cell that matches the input, which is a modified version of this code: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/21/find-all-instances-with-vba

```
Function SelectedRange(ByVal fnd As String) As Range

Dim FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

  Loop

  Set SelectedRange = rng

'Report Out Message
  MsgBox SelectedRange.Cells.Count & " cell(s) were found containing: " & fnd

Exit Function

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
  MsgBox "No cells containing: " & fnd & " were found in this worksheet"

End Function
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't disclosed *exactly* what *SelectedRange* references; hopefully it isn't a union of discontiguous cells.

Use *SelectedRange* in a [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) and you can access its dimensions for the [Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
dim SelectedRange as range
set SelectedRange = range("B2:D4")
with SelectedRange
    set SelectedRange = .resize(.rows.count, .columns.count + 3)
end with
SelectedRange.select    'might want to get away from this method
```

For a discontiguous arrangement of cells, you need to loop through the [Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174786%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and resize each while adding it to a collective with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx).

```
Dim a As Long, selectedRange As Range, tmpRange As Range
Set selectedRange = Selection
Set tmpRange = selectedRange.Range("A1")
With selectedRange
    For a = 1 To .Areas.Count
        With .Areas(a)
            Set tmpRange = Union(tmpRange, .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count + 3))
        End With
    Next a
End With
Set selectedRange = tmpRange
selectedRange.Select   'might want to get away from this method
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Updated with SelectedRange. Is there an issue with a union of discontiguous cells?

Comment: A union of discontiguous cells may have groups (or *areas*) of cells with different numbers of columns. Each has to be dealt with individually. See above.